# C expression must have pointer to struct or union type

Tags: c, pointers, structure

I'm using CCS v6 and there was an error about structure grammar.

```
typedef struct _mem_ptr_t
{
    struct _mem_ptr_t *next;    ///< Next pointer in memory
    uint8    alloc;              ///< Allocated
    struct  mmem mmem_ptr;      ///< The actual pointer to the pointer to the mem block
} mem_ptr_t;

struct mmem {
  struct mmem *next;
  unsigned int size;
  void *ptr;
};
```

above code was original state. but there was an error.
"#71 incomplete type is not allowed "

So, I had changed code "struct  mmem mmem_ptr; " -> "struct  mmem *mmem_ptr; "
When i had compiling, that part was passed.

But another part was occurred error.

```
if ((mem_ptr = mac_scan_alloc()) != NULL) {
        memcpy(&SCAN_ENTRY(mem_ptr)->oord_addr, src_addr, sizeof(address_t));
        SCAN_ENTRY(mem_ptr)->superfrm_spec = superframe_spec;
        SCAN_ENTRY(mem_ptr)->coord_pan_id = src_pan_id;
        SCAN_ENTRY(mem_ptr)->channel = channel;
    }
#define SCAN_ENTRY(m)  ((pan_descr_t *)MMEM_PTR(&m->mmem_ptr))
```

There was an error "#133 expression must have pointer-to-struct-or-union type"

I had already looked related question about this problem. but i couldn't understand to solve above problem. [Expression must have pointer to struct or union error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29874490/expression-must-have-pointer-to-struct-or-union-error)

What should i fix my code to solve this problem?

Comment: Definition of `SCAN_ENTRY`?

Comment: @EugeneSh.: It's already posted. Anyway, `#define SCAN_ENTRY(m)  ((pan_descr_t *)MMEM_PTR(&m->mmem_ptr))` probably suffers from excessive ampersand.

Comment: Right.. but why *after* it is used?

Comment: @EugeneSh.: That's actually a *really* good question...

Comment: oh i'm sorry. it was just mixed code. SCAN_ENTRY is located header file !

Answer (score 4):

`struct _mem_ptr_t` uses `struct  mmem` before it is defined.  So swap the definitions:

```
struct mmem {
  struct mmem *next;
  unsigned int size;
  void *ptr;
};

typedef struct _mem_ptr_t
{
    struct _mem_ptr_t *next;    ///< Next pointer in memory
    uint8    alloc;              ///< Allocated
    struct  mmem mmem_ptr;      ///< The actual pointer to the pointer to the mem block
} mem_ptr_t;
```

Changing the definition of `mmem_ptr` from `struct mmem` to `struct mmem *` doesn't work because you're changing its type, so any code that uses it is not doing so properly.